# Match index of string starting from end until a digit is hit

Tags: python, regex, string, substring

I have a python string that is a document number in the format of

**'A87-0000E000' or 'TRS-0000E000'**

When I parse a word document for the document number, sometimes I'm getting dates and other information I don't want in the string. Is there a way to match a regular expression, or substring starting from the end of the string going backward until I get a digit?

## String length is not fixed since it comes from a word document.

## Example

```
line = 'A97-5000E000 Date:'
```

## Expected Output

```
line = 'A97-5000E000'
```

---

## Example 2

```
line = 'TRS 4000E000 Page 1 of'
```

## Expected Output

```
line = 'TRS 4000E000'
```

---

## Example 3

```
line = 'TRS 3000231 Date: Dec, 12 20'
```

## Expected Output

```
line = 'TRS 3000231'
```

Comment: can you share a full input and the expected output please?

Comment: How do you know the filename isn't "TRS 4000E000 Page 1 of 5"?  You haven't given any reason why that can't be the filename. Do you have any objection to simply looking for "Page" or "Date" and using those as separators? I know you gave some examples, but you are rejecting answers that follow that format, so we need a better definition of the format.

Comment: The string comes from the header of the word document, so I can be sure it isn't the name of the file. Looking for Page or Date might actually be the simplest solution to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex `([A-Z0-9]{3}[- ])([A-Z0-9]+)\s.*` which can :

- `([A-Z0-9]{3}[- ])` match a group of uppercase letter and degits of length 3 followed by `-` or `space`
- `([A-Z0-9]+)` second group which matche uppercase letter and degits before the next space

So the final result is group 1 and group 2 `$1$2`

## regex demo

Comment: What's the difference between group(1) and group(0). I've seen sometimes group(0) matches my string, while sometimes group(1) does.

Comment: @ProfessionalNameForDisplayHere i makes a mistake i mean `the final result is group 1 and group 2 $1$2` group1 and group2

Answer (score 0):

if the length of the part you want is fixed, you can use slice :
`line[:12]`

Comment: The string length can vary because I'm getting it from a text document.

Comment: The format is fixed length in all the examples given in the original question.